# How to activate and disable jQuery 'click' events on an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, web-frontend, client-side-scripting

I have a button with two click events attached to it. I am having trouble disabling one 'click' event while keeping on another.

need to have functionality so on the first click will alert("first was clicked"),  on the second click will alert("second was clicked"), on the third click will alert("first was clicked"), on fourth click will alert("second was clicked") and so on...

```
<button id="clickable">
```

```
$('#clickable').on('click', function first_click () {

    alert("first was clicked");

$("#clickable").off('click', first_click);

    $('#clickable').on('click', function second_click () {

       alert("second was clicked");

  // need to have functionality so on the first click will alert("first was clicked"),  on the second click will alert("second was clicked"), on the third click will alert("first was clicked"), on fourth click will alert("second was clicked") and so on...    

     });

});
```

Comment: use boolean flag to identify click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var checkFlag = true;
function clicked(){
  if(checkFlag == true){
  alert("first clicked");
  }else{
  alert("Second clicked");
  }
  checkFlag = !checkFlag;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="clicked();">Click</button>
```

use boolean flag to check

Answer (score 0):

jQuery code:

```
// making disabled
$("#clickable").attr('disabled', '')

// making enabled
$("#clickable").removeAttr('disabled')
```

Also you might plain JS code for to complete this operation.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("clickable");

// making disabled
btn.setAttribute("disabled", ""); 

// making enabled
btn.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific class to your button when it's the first click and check if she if there or not then you can know if you are in the first or second click

```js
$('#clickable').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).is(".step")) {
      // first click
      $(this).addClass('step');
      console.log("first was clicked");
    } else {
      // second click
      $(this).removeClass('step');
      console.log("second was clicked");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="clickable">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
      var clickCount = 1;
      document.getElementById("clickable").addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(clickCount % 2 != 0){
      alert("first was clicked")
           clickCount++;
        }else{
      alert("second was clicked")
           clickCount++;
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
var step = true;
$("#clickable").on('click', function(e) {
    msg = step ? 'first' : 'second';
    alert(msg + ' was clicked!')
    step = !step;
})})()
```